# how to pass instantiated object to camera

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, camera, parameter-passing

i'm instantiating an object in my scene, now i want the camera to follow it how can i do that ?
the object is instantiated but i don't know how can i pass the object to my camera target;
and you cant drag instantiated object to inspector

```
public class TankManager : MonoBehaviour
{
void Start()
{
    Instantiate (MenuManager.SelectedCharacter, Vector3.zero, Quaternion.identity);
}}
```

my camera code :

```
public class FollowCamera : MonoBehaviour{
public Transform target;
public Vector3 offsetPosition;
public Space offsetPositionSpace = Space.Self;
public bool lookAt = true;

private void Update()
{
    Refresh();
}

public void Refresh()
{
    if(target == null)
    {
        Debug.LogWarning("Missing target ref !", this);

        return;
    }

    if(offsetPositionSpace == Space.Self)
    {
        transform.position = target.TransformPoint(offsetPosition);
    }
    else
    {
        transform.position = target.position + offsetPosition;
    }

    if(lookAt)
    {
        transform.LookAt(target);
    }
    else
    {
        transform.rotation = target.rotation;
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your target variable is public, so make a reference to it inside the TankManager script.
Presuming that you have the TankManager script attached to a GameObject in the Hierarchy, the script should look like this:

```
public class TankManager : MonoBehaviour
{

public Camera camera;
FollowCamera followC;

    void Start()
    {
        GameObject target = Instantiate (MenuManager.SelectedCharacter, Vector3.zero, Quaternion.identity);
        followC = camera.GetComponent <FollowCamera>();
        followC.target = target;
   }
}
```

Then just drag and drop the camera into the TankManager inspector area.

Comment: thanks brother it worked ;but a little enhancement  for those who reading gameobject should be transform and it needs a cast too;